# Call another class in IOS

Tags: ios, class, view, overlay, uitabcontroller

I'm new on IOS platform and after study a little about how does it works, i had one doubt about how to call a new class/view and overlay the current view when a button is pressed. In android i do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(a.class, b.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Searching on internet, i noticed that i have to use navigation bars to do it. I start an app with tab bar controller and putted a navigation controller. I used the code below:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *myController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Dicas"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: myController animated:YES];
```

and the return:
[image]
There is a way to overlay the current view? I always have to use navigation bars to call another class (use bottom e upper controllers will make my app ugly)?

Comment: if the navigation bar and the too bar bother you, just hide them...

Comment: Look at the docs for `presentViewController:animated:completion:` for a different option that's outside the navigation hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the navigation bar:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

To hide tab bar:

```
yourViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also call another viewController by using presentViewController function of a viewController class.

```
[self presentViewController: myController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said u want to overlay your current view so not sure but You can show your view controller using model view like this

```
yourViewController *secView = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
[secView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];//u can use different UIModalPresentationStyle
[secView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:secView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Above one will show your view controller over existing view controller, once presented you need to make provision to dismiss this modal view.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to present new class or ViewController like this..

```
  ViewController *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
  [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```